# Error: Registration token(s) provided to sendToDevice()

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

Now im working for my final project. I try to send notification using firebase cloud function when its trigger the onUpdate but i got an error. I have follow tutorial on youtube and website but i dont get it. By the way, im new to firebase. below Here is my index.js code :-

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');

//Firebase function and handling notification logic

const admin = require('firebase-admin');

admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);

exports.pushNotification = functions.database.ref('/Sensor').onWrite(( change,context) => {

const sensor = change.after.val();

const payload = {
        notification: {

            Title: "Alert",
            Body: "Open pipe detect !",
            icon: "default"
            }
        };

    return admin.messaging().sendToDevice(sensor.token, payload)
    .then((response)=> {
    return console.log("Successfully sent message:", response);
    });
  });
```

the project structure is like this:

```
**water-system**    
    +--Sensor  
        +---Pipe
        +---pipeName
        +---solenoid
        +---status  // trigger on this update


+---User
     +---Id1
         +---email
         +---name 
         +---token // token store by this user
     +---Id2
     +---Id3
         +---token // also store token
```

So when the child node of Sensor have been update it will send notification to User who have store the token(user id1 and id3). Glad if anyone could help me to solve this problem

Comment: whats the error youre getting

Comment: https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/admin/send-messages per the docs here looks like the token should an array of strings

Comment: i get this error @JayLane Error: Registration token(s) provided to sendToDevice() must be a non-empty string or a non-empty array.

Comment: @JayLane: The [legacy API sendToDevice()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/admin/legacy-fcm#send_to_individual_devices) is being used here.

Comment: @BobSnyder just noticed

Comment: In your DB, `Sensor` does not have a child value for `token`

Answer (score 0):

Try storing the tokens in this format:

```
  "tokens" : {
    "cXyVF6oUGuo:APA91bHTSUPy31JjMVTYK" : true,
    "deL50wnXUZ0:APA91bGAF-kWMNxyP6LGH" : true,
    "dknxCjdSQ1M:APA91bGFkKeQxB8KPHz4o" : true,
    "eZunoQspodk:APA91bGzG4J302zS7sfUW" : true
  }
```

Whenever you want to write a new token just do a set:

```
firebase.app().database().ref(`/user/${uid}/tokens/${token}`).set(true);
```

And to create an array for sendToDevice:

```
  const tokensList = Object.keys(tokens.val());
  return admin.messaging().sendToDevice(tokensList, payload);
```